# Execute method with a return type and input parameter in parallel

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, parallel-processing

I have the below code. I want to execute `m3()` in parallel by 3 threads as I am executing m1 and m2.

How can I achieve it. I am using Spring Boot and java 8. Is it possible to execute `m3()` using executor service.

```
@Service
class Main {
    @Autowired
    Private Other other;
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
   
    void test_method() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 201; i++) {
            executorService.submit(() -> other.m1()); // works fine as expected 
            executorService.submit(() -> other.m2()); // works fine as expected 
            executorService.submit(() -> other.m3(i)); // compilation error  as expected
    }
}
```

Error is

> Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or
> effectively final

The methods are below

```
@Service
class Other {
    void m1() {
    }
    
    String m2() {
        return "Hello";
    }
 
    int m3(int n) {
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you cannot use non-final variables in anonymous inner classes, i.e. lambda expressions as well.

- A *final* variable is one which is instantiated only one time.
- An *effectively-final* variable is one who's value never changes after the initialization.

One possible workaround is using `IntStream.range` and `IntStream.forEach` methods:

```
IntStream.range(0, 201).forEach(i -> {
    executorService.submit(() -> other.m1());
    executorService.submit(() -> other.m2());
    executorService.submit(() -> other.m3(i));
});
```

Comment: Thanks .But your method will work for int.Suppose i was passing some custom Pojo like MyObject  to m3() then how would i do it?Any elegant way to do it?

Comment: Enchanted loop works: `for (Pojo pojo: list) { executorService.submit(() -> other.m3(pojo)); }`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
void test_method() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 201; i++) {
        executorService.submit(other::m1);
        executorService.submit(other::m2);
        final int i1 = i;
        executorService.submit(() -> other.m3(i1));        
    }
}
```

Comment: i will try thanks.And i solved the problem by using creating a container class for int 
`final MyContainer myContainer = new MyContainer(i);
myContainer.getIntValue()`.But do you have any elegant solution to execute m3() in parallel with ot without ExecutorService

Comment: and your and my solution is almost same.But suppose i was passing some custom Pojo class to m3

Comment: @PaleBlueDot execute m3() in parallel with what? it is already execuded with maximal possible logical parallelism. To achieve maximum physical parallelism, use  
   ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());